# Configure Micromax MMX 352G USB 3G Modem and Aircel in Ubuntu Server 12.04 to connect to internet

Tags: server, usb-modem

I'm Interested to use Ubuntu Server 12.04 command line only OS to boost my knowledge of linux in depth. I installed it to my DELL Inspiron 1120 Laptop, But I am not able to connect to internet using my Micromax MMX 352G USB 3G Modem ( I'm using Aircel Pocket Internet as ISP with APN "aircelweb" for 2G Network). I don't know how to configure my modem to connect to internet. My lsusb output is a follows:

```
odswct@odswct:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:58f3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c9e:9605 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY 
odswct@odswct:~$
```

My modem is detected at last line as "OMEGA TECHNOLOGY".
Is any one there to help me for the configuration in details.

It works fine when I am using this modem with Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 after a modprobe for usbserial. But I want to configure it for Ubuntu Server 12.04 without using sakis3g script.

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot help you much with the details, you need to take a look at wvdial to use your USB 3G modem from commandline. I think it should appear on /dev/modem.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto/SetUpDialer#Alternative_Way_1_.28using_wvdialconf_.26_wvdial.29

In order to test that the modem is working fine, you can plug it and try to connect to it with :

```
screen /dev/modem
```

and test various AT commands. For example, typing ATI + enter should give you the model of your modem ( if I am not wrong )

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps try [the link here](http://www.micromaxinfo.com/product.php?cat=all&product=310G).

I haven't tried it yet, and I'm on Debian...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! That's appears to just be the manufacturer's page for the device. Why would that help? Is there information there, somewhere, that explains how to troubleshoot the device on Linux-based systems? Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. I recommend editing this answer, at least to clarify how that source pertains to the question asked.